# Does React handle keys automatically when using React.Children.map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm well aware of the [reasons](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) why one needs to add a `key` prop when creating dynamic children in React. What's intriguing to me is the behavior of the below two pieces of code

This iterates over `children` using just [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <span>Child 1</span>
      <span>Child 2</span>
      <span>Child 3</span>
    </Parent>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  return children.map(child => (
    <div style={{ background: "lightblue" }}>{child}</div>
  ));
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app">
```

This uses [`React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) to do the same

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <span>Child 1</span>
      <span>Child 2</span>
      <span>Child 3</span>
    </Parent>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => (
    <div style={{ background: "lightblue" }}>{child}</div>
  ));
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app">
```

The first snippet produces a warning

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

whereas the second one doesn't produce any. So the two questions I have are:

1. Does `React.Children.map` auto-generate keys for the elements we pass through it?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, then does it guarantee that the keys will remain unique and consistent across re-renders? By consistent I mean, re-ordered elements will produce the same keys when passed through it

Comment: you can check if it produces the key attribute by checking the DOM

Comment: I just tried checking the DOM after running the example snippet. I don't see any key attribute. Are you aware of how I could check that maybe?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Install "React Developer Tool" chrome extension and navigate to React tab while inspecting elements. That will help in finding if the `key` property is being set

Comment: Keys are **always** auto-generated when mapping, regardless if you use `React.Children.map` or not. The key will always be the index of the item in the array unless you've specified otherwise. Even when you get the warning, React has used the index. The difference is that `React.Children.map` does not throw a warning about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `React.Children.map` takes into account the `key` that you have
>   provided for the child components and adds a prefix to them, if the
>   **key is not provided** to the children components, **it adds a Implicit key**
>   determined by the index in the set while iterating to the mapped
>   object

Below is a excerpt from the [`mapChildren`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6565795377d1d2c79a7708766f1af9e1a87517de/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js) function form React src

```
function getComponentKey(component, index) {
  // Do some typechecking here since we call this blindly. We want to ensure
  // that we don't block potential future ES APIs.
  if (
    typeof component === 'object' &&
    component !== null &&
    component.key != null
  ) {
    // Explicit key
    return escape(component.key);
  }
  // Implicit key determined by the index in the set
  return index.toString(36);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source. Does this mean that if we use `React.Children.map`, we won't get the optimizations that are supposed to be gained by using keys? Because React is auto-prefixing some keys by itself based on index?

Comment: Keys don’t give you “optimizations”. They ensure React can determine what moved and got deleted (instead of trying to always update items in order). But yes, you’re right this doesn’t help it do that.

Comment: @DanAbramov I was referring to what you've mentioned as an optimization. I guess it wasn't the right word. So, it's better to use Array#map instead of React.Children.map for creating dynamic children?

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!!  I wish this was more clear in the docs since it's exactly what is needed if you want to implement a wrapper for a list, e.g., to create a lazy loading list.  Before I found this I was hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out how I could do this transparently while benefiting from the keys already assigned to the children!

Comment: @maazadeeb  Depends.  If the underlying children are already keyed then using React.Children.map lets you use them without the wrapping component needing to know the keys.