# React key prop within wrapper

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-key-index

While looking through our code base, I found code that looks a bit like this:

```
const Carousel = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <CarouselOuter>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <CarouselItemWrapper>
          <CarouselItem key={item.key}>
            ...
          </CarouselItem>
        </CarouselItemWrapper>
      )}
    </CarouselOuter>
  );
}
```

Notice that the `key` prop is on `CarouselItem`, not `CarouselItemWrapper`, the component that's directly returned from `items.map`. This seems to work fine, and there are no warnings in the console, but it runs counter to every example I've seen using `map` in React.

I want know if there's a good argument (specifically in regards to performance) for rearranging the code with the `key` as shown below, or if this is just a stylistic choice:

```
const Carousel = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <CarouselOuter>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <CarouselItemWrapper key={item.key}>
          <CarouselItem>
            ...
          </CarouselItem>
        </CarouselItemWrapper>
      )}
    </CarouselOuter>
  );
}
```

Side note: `CarouselOuter`, `CarouselItem`, and `CarouselItemWrapper` are all [styled-components](/questions/tagged/styled-components), but I doubt that's relevant.

Comment: The key attribute needs to be on the direct child, I tested myself and i get a warning if i put the key on the second level child. I found this subject who might answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303465/does-react-handle-keys-automatically-when-using-react-children-map

Comment: You can check what key are set to each child by check the react dev tool :) I found this in the react code base, might interest you https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6565795377d1d2c79a7708766f1af9e1a87517de/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js

Comment: @Zerowiel Actually, you're right. There is a warning, we just missed it earlier. Thank you for the links.

Comment: i was curious about your question that's why i tested it myself and found some edge case in the github i linked to you. If you use children.map there is no warning if you don't use key :p