# React - generating a unique random key causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I have a componenet that wraps its children and slides them in and out based on the `stage` prop, which represents the active child's index.

As this uses a `.map()` to wrap each child in a div for styling, I need to give each child a `key` prop. I want to assign a random key as the `children` could be anything.

I thought I could just do this

```
key={`pageSlide-${uuid()}`}
```

but it causes an infinite loop/React to freeze and I can't figure out why

I have tried

- Mapping the children before render and adding a `uuid` key there, calling it via `key={child.uuid}`
- Creating an array of uuids and assigning them via `key={uuids[i]}`
- Using a custom hook to store the children in a state and assign a uuid prop there

All result in the same issue

Currently I'm just using the child's index as a key `key={`pageSlide-${i}`}` which works but is not best practice and I want to learn why this is happening.

I can also assign the key directly to the child in the parent component and then use `child.key` but this kinda defeats the point of generating the key

(uuid is a function from react-uuid, but the same issue happens with any function including Math.random())

Here is the full component:

```
import {
    Children,
    useCallback,
    useEffect,
    useMemo,
    useRef,
    useState,
} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import ProgressBarWithTicks from "./ProgressBarWithTicks";
import { childrenPropType } from "../../../propTypes/childrenPropTypes";

const calculateTranslateX = (i = 0, stage = 0) => {
    let translateX = stage === i ? 0 : 100;
    if (i < stage) {
        translateX = -100;
    }
    return translateX;
};

const ComponentSlider = ({ stage, children, stageCounter }) => {
    const childComponents = Children.toArray(children);
    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    const [lastResize, setLastResize] = useState(null);
    const [currentMaxHeight, setCurrentMaxHeight] = useState(
        containerRef.current?.childNodes?.[stage]?.clientHeight
    );

    const updateMaxHeight = useCallback(
        (scrollToTop = true) => {
            if (scrollToTop) {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
            setCurrentMaxHeight(
                Math.max(
                    containerRef.current?.childNodes?.[stage]?.clientHeight,
                    window.innerHeight -
                        (containerRef?.current?.offsetTop || 0) -
                        48
                )
            );
        },
        [stage]
    );

    useEffect(updateMaxHeight, [stage, updateMaxHeight]);
    useEffect(() => updateMaxHeight(false), [lastResize, updateMaxHeight]);

    const resizeListener = useMemo(
        () => new MutationObserver(() => setLastResize(Date.now())),
        []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            resizeListener.observe(containerRef.current, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true,
            });
        }
    }, [resizeListener]);

    return (
        <div className="w-100">
            {stageCounter && (
                <ProgressBarWithTicks
                    currentStage={stage}
                    stages={childComponents.length}
                />
            )}
            <div
                className="position-relative divSlider align-items-start"
                ref={containerRef}
                style={{
                    maxHeight: currentMaxHeight || null,
                }}>
                {Children.map(childComponents, (child, i) => (
                    <div
                        key={`pageSlide-${uuid()}`}
                        className={`w-100 ${
                            stage === i ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
                        } justify-content-center d-flex`}
                        style={{
                            zIndex: childComponents.length - i,
                            transform: `translateX(${calculateTranslateX(
                                i,
                                stage
                            )}%)`,
                            pointerEvents: stage === i ? null : "none",
                            cursor: stage === i ? null : "none",
                        }}>
                        {child}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ComponentSlider.propTypes = {
    children: childrenPropType.isRequired,
    stage: PropTypes.number,
    stageCounter: PropTypes.bool,
};

ComponentSlider.defaultProps = {
    stage: 0,
    stageCounter: false,
};

export default ComponentSlider;
```

It is only called in this component (twice, happens in both instances)

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import {
    FaCalendarCheck,
    FaCalendarPlus,
    FaHandHoldingHeart,
} from "react-icons/fa";
import { IoIosCart } from "react-icons/io";
import { mockMatches } from "../../../templates/mockData";
import { initialSwapFormState } from "../../../templates/initalStates";
import swapReducer from "../../../reducers/swapReducer";
import useFetch from "../../../hooks/useFetch";
import useValidateFields from "../../../hooks/useValidateFields";
import IconWrap from "../../common/IconWrap";
import ComponentSlider from "../../common/transitions/ComponentSlider";
import ConfirmNewSwap from "./ConfirmSwap";
import SwapFormWrapper from "./SwapFormWrapper";
import MatchSwap from "../Matches/MatchSwap";
import SwapOffers from "./SwapOffers";
import CreateNewSwap from "./CreateNewSwap";
import smallNumberToWord from "../../../functions/utils/numberToWord";
import ComponentFader from "../../common/transitions/ComponentFader";

const formStageHeaders = [
    "What shift do you want to swap?",
    "What shifts can you do instead?",
    "Pick a matching shift",
    "Good to go!",
];

const NewSwap = () => {
    const { swapIdParam } = useParams();
    const [formStage, setFormStage] = useState(0);
    const [swapId, setSwapId] = useState(swapIdParam || null);
    const [newSwap, dispatchNewSwap] = useReducer(swapReducer, {
        ...initialSwapFormState,
    });

    const [matches, setMatches] = useState(mockMatches);

    const [selectedMatch, setSelectedMatch] = useState(null);
    const [validateHook, newSwapValidationErrors] = useValidateFields(newSwap);

    const fetchHook = useFetch();
    const setStage = (stageIndex) => {
        if (!swapId && stageIndex > 1) {
            setSwapId(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
        }
        if (stageIndex === "reset") {
            setSwapId(null);
            dispatchNewSwap({ type: "reset" });
        }
        setFormStage(stageIndex === "reset" ? 0 : stageIndex);
    };

    const saveMatch = async () => {
        const matchResponse = await fetchHook({
            type: "addSwap",
            options: { body: newSwap },
        });
        if (matchResponse.success) {
            setStage(3);
        } else {
            setMatches([]);
            dispatchNewSwap({ type: "setSwapMatch" });
            setStage(1);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // set matchId of new selected swap
        dispatchNewSwap({ type: "setSwapMatch", payload: selectedMatch });
    }, [selectedMatch]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="my-3">
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center w-100 my-3">
                    <ComponentSlider stage={formStage}>
                        <IconWrap colour="primary">
                            <FaCalendarPlus />
                        </IconWrap>
                        <IconWrap colour="danger">
                            <FaHandHoldingHeart />
                        </IconWrap>
                        <IconWrap colour="warning">
                            <IoIosCart />
                        </IconWrap>
                        <IconWrap colour="success">
                            <FaCalendarCheck />
                        </IconWrap>
                    </ComponentSlider>
                </div>
                <ComponentFader stage={formStage}>
                    {formStageHeaders.map((x) => (
                        <h3
                            key={`stageHeading-${x.id}`}
                            className="text-center my-3">
                            {x}
                        </h3>
                    ))}
                </ComponentFader>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
                <ComponentSlider stage={formStage} stageCounter>
                    <SwapFormWrapper heading="Shift details">
                        <CreateNewSwap
                            setSwapId={setSwapId}
                            newSwap={newSwap}
                            newSwapValidationErrors={newSwapValidationErrors}
                            dispatchNewSwap={dispatchNewSwap}
                            validateFunction={validateHook}
                            setStage={setStage}
                        />
                    </SwapFormWrapper>
                    <SwapFormWrapper heading="Swap in return offers">
                        <p>
                            You can add up to{" "}
                            {smallNumberToWord(5).toLowerCase()} offers, and
                            must have at least one
                        </p>
                        <SwapOffers
                            swapId={swapId}
                            setStage={setStage}
                            newSwap={newSwap}
                            dispatchNewSwap={dispatchNewSwap}
                            setMatches={setMatches}
                        />
                    </SwapFormWrapper>
                    <SwapFormWrapper>
                        <MatchSwap
                            swapId={swapId}
                            setStage={setStage}
                            matches={matches}
                            selectedMatch={selectedMatch}
                            setSelectedMatch={setSelectedMatch}
                            dispatchNewSwap={dispatchNewSwap}
                            saveMatch={saveMatch}
                        />
                    </SwapFormWrapper>
                    <SwapFormWrapper>
                        <ConfirmNewSwap
                            swapId={swapId}
                            setStage={setStage}
                            selectedSwap={selectedMatch}
                            newSwap={newSwap}
                        />
                    </SwapFormWrapper>
                </ComponentSlider>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

NewSwap.propTypes = {};

export default NewSwap;
```

**One solution**

@Nick Parsons has pointed out I don't even need a `key` if using `React.Children.map()`, so this is a non issue

I'd still really like to understand what was causing this problem, aas far as I can tell `updateMaxHeight` is involved, but I can't quite see the chain that leads to an constant re-rendering

Interstingly if I use `useMemo` for an array of uuids it works

```
const uuids = useMemo(
    () => Array.from({ length: childComponents.length }).map(() => uuid()),
    [childComponents.length]
);

/*...*/
key={uuids[i]}
```

Comment: You don't need to provide a `key` if you're using `React.Children.map()`, React will either use a prefixed version of the `key` on the child component, or it will use the index of the child element (which is ok to do since your children are hard-coded). More info here: [Does React handle keys automatically when using React.Children.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303840)

Comment: oh wow you're right, I only recently changed to `Children.map()` instead of a plain `.map()` and wasn't aware so you've totally fixed this for me - I would still like to understand what causes the crash if you have any ideas? It seems to be related to the `updateMaxHeight` which sets some state and I guess that means generating a new uuid but I don't see how that would then cause another render?

Comment: React uses the key prop to see which items need to be rerendered on state changes, so if every childs key changes that means they need to get rendered again which causes the loop.

Comment: Ah ok, so new state -> new render -> new key but shouldn't it stop there? I think I understand what you're saying, I just can't see exactly where the loop was occuring, not why commenting out `updateMaxHeight` stopped the loop